# What is this dark brown liquid my cat palm is producing?

Tags: diagnosis, palm

Today I have noticed that one of my cat palms is producing a dark brown liquid on its stem. It is a female palm, which is producing seeds right now and all the leaves are green and healthy. Since I believe this is a disease, I cut two leaves to inspect the area, but could not figure out what is going on. The smell of the substance is fruity. Could someone please shed a light on this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your palm is beautiful!      I've been growing Cat palms for years and have never seen any dark fluid before. I wonder if it could be from an insect or rotting plant matter. Good luck.